# SwiftUI iOS15 Image being animated from top left corner instead of cetner

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, ios15

I ma having an unusual issue.I have a loading screen where the center image is suppose to give a heart beat animation. I am accomplishing this by using the scaleEffect. This works fine in iOS 16. However, in iOS 15 (and even 15.4) The animation is wrong.

What is happening is that the animation's reference point is in the top-left corner instead of the picture's center. Additionally, it appears that the entire view is animating rather then the picture.

Coud I get some feedback on my code? I believe that I am setting something incorrectly or maybe there is a better way of accomplishing what I want.

The issue is happening in the LoadingView struct

```swift
struct LoadingView: View{
    
    @State private var animatingLogo = false
    
    var body: some View{
       // GeometryReader{geoReader in
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 6) {
                Image("JHLogo")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .scaleEffect(animatingLogo ? 0.15 : 0.1, anchor: .center)
                    .onAppear{
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever()){
                            animatingLogo.toggle()
                            }
                    }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)

    }
}
```

And here is the top level view in case this is the one that has the issue:

```swift
// Initial view that is loaded on app startup
struct MainView: View{
    @State private var isLoading = false
    
    var body : some View {
        GeometryReader{geoReader in
            NavigationView {
                if (isLoading) {
                    LoadingView()
                }
                else {
                    CoverPageView()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: geoReader.size.width, height:geoReader.size.height)
            .fixedSize()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .onAppear {
                startLoadingScreen()
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    func startLoadingScreen() {
        isLoading = true;
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3){
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I replace your image with a system image it all runs fine. I think you are missing a `.resizable` on the image? And maybe its something else wrong with the image ... Also you don't need the `GeometryReader` in `MainView` as well as all the view modifiers.

Comment: Yes! It looks like that it was geometry reader giving me an issue